# Query a database for empty tables

Tags: mysql

In my system there are two tables called ‘faculty’ and ‘faculty_assets’.

I need to delete faculty by faculty from the ‘faculty’ table. But system should allow deleting the faculty when only faculty_assets table empty. Otherwise It should not allows to delete the faculties from ‘faculty’ table.

Can anyone modify below sql query?  (‘fac_id’ is the primary key of ‘faculty’ table )

```
function removeFaculty($fac_id){
    $conn=new connection();
    $sql="delete from faculty where fac_id='$fac_id'";
    $result=$conn->query($sql);
    return $result;
```

}

Comment: You need a foreign key with on delete cascade.

Comment: You may get more comprehensive answers if you post the schemas for both tables.  Nevertheless I will give it a go based on some assumptions.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming faculty_assets and faculty are joined by the fac_id field, you could use something like

```
$sql="DELETE FROM faculty WHERE fac_id='" . (int)$fac_id . "' AND NOT EXISTS 
        (SELECT * FROM faculty_assets WHERE fac_id = '".(int)$fac_id . "')";
```

Comment: -1 for not taking the opportunity to remove the SQL injection vulnerability and to warn about it in your answer.

Comment: We don't know that the $fac_id field wasn't sanitized prior to being passed in as a parameter.  It's not like he used $_POST['fac_id'].